# A good way to represent an object with multiple interconnected states?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

I want to program a simple budget application. In my application, the budget is divided into budget periods (months by default, but it can be bi-weekly or weekly periods). In each period there is a list of spending categories.

The user can perform different action on a category, like to record a spending, allocate budget, create new category, close existing category etc. So each category should have a different state for each period, but the changes for particular state of specific period should influence the category state of consecutive period (any change in spending/budgeting in January should change the state of a category in February). So each period should have a specific state of category that is belong to him and he can operate on, but the category itself should be able to see the changes that are made and perform changes in other states.

Initially I was thinking to implement a category as a list of its states, but my gut telling me that it's not a good design. I would really like to hear if there is a better design/design patter that can be used here.

Answer (score 2):

From a high level point of view, it seems that you're searching for the observer pattern. You can turn your States into `observables`, and your Categories into `observers` (assuming you have abstractions for both your States and Categories). This way, whenever you create a new category, you can make it observe the already existing states, so that when they update, they can warn their observers to do so as well.

Comment: Ok, but how does this address the problem of the state related to the period for a category ?

Answer (score 1):

According to your narrative:

- `Budget` is decomposed in `Period` which have several `Category`
- The user experience is `Category` centric, and the same `Category` is used across several `Period`.

This means that there is an many-to-many association between `Period` and `Category`.  In an RDBMS, you would typically map this with an [association table](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/associationTableMapping.html).  You could add additional properties to such association using an [association class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCLKU_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cassnclss.html).  In the RDBMS mapping, these properties would then be additional columns of the association table.

And this is exactly what you want:  to have an association between `Period` and `Category` and an association class (let's call it `CategoryPeriod`) that represents the state that corresponds to the occurence of that association (e.g. `Category` "Rent" for `Period` 2018-11 has `budget_amount` of $500). The state of the `CategoryPeriod` is the state you are looking for.

Now, you guess right:  having these states as a list in `Category` is not ideal, unless it is sorted.  I'd rather go for a `map<Period>`.  If you go for a DDD design, you could also have the `CategoryRepository` implement a method to get a specific `CategoryPeriod` or a set of several items for the same `Category`.

Now for the impact of an update of `CategoryRepository` for period n,  the easiest is to implement this operation via the Category aggregate root, and trigger the update of all the items for subsequent periods in the same category.